# From IF/ELSE to Switch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

So, I'm trying to substitute the code within the IF statements to run the same way in a Switch statement. However, I can't seem to understand how to get the functions to run the same way in the switch as they do in the if statement.  Here's the code I've written with the if statement.  Could anyone help me figure out how to format it correctly to run with the switch statement instead?

```
function processInput() {

    listitem = "item" + i;
    document.getElementById(listitem).innerHTML = document.getElementById('toolBox').value;
    document.getElementById('toolBox').value = '';

    if (i == 5) {

      document.getElementById('resultsExpl').innerHTML = "Thanks for your suggestions";

    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: why do you think your need a `switch` statement here?

Comment: You have a single `if` and no `else`. How is a `switch` supposed to work here?

Comment: Where is `i` defined? This isn't much use to anyone for debugging.

Comment: show us your switch statement.  Perhaps it's a simple syntax issue, or missing break statement.

Comment: @Jcl, nothing prevents you from having a `switch` with just one `case` … whether that any makes sense whatsoever, would be a different question.

Comment: @CBroe oh yes, that's what I meant with "work". Not saying it can't be done :-)

Comment: @ergonaut, that's the issue.  I'm trying to translate this into a switch statement. I realize I may not be providing enough information, let me know what else I could provide to help out!

Comment: @NewToJS i is defined as a global variable before this code.  It's var i = 1; and then var listitem = "";

Comment: @SethSpivey Do you not think it would be a good idea to display related/relevant source code? For all we know `i` could be the reason you're having problems.

Comment: @NewToJS it would.  Sorry about the mess up.

Comment: @SethSpivey your biggest mess up is telling people they're doing your assignments for you. I will be sure to avoid any further questions you have.

Comment: @NewToJS fair enough.  Thanks for making me understand I should be exhausting all other options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want the switch but for sample purposes here is how a switch would work for the code you posted above:

```
function processInput() {

    listitem = "item" + i;
    document.getElementById(listitem).innerHTML = document.getElementById('toolBox').value;
    document.getElementById('toolBox').value = '';

    switch(i) {
        case 5:
           document.getElementById('resultsExpl').innerHTML = "Thanks for your suggestions";
           break;

        default:
           // any code you want to run in the else statement
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: It's for an assignment I'm working on right now and the requirement is to translate from if to switch.

Comment: @SethSpivey So you have others doing your assignments for you rather than doing research and learning? Tell your tutor you don't have any interest in development, I'm sure it will save you and your tutor a lot of wasted time.

Answer (score 1):

This switch statement would replace the current if statement that you have.

```
switch (i) {
    case 5:
        document.getElementById('resultsExpl').innerHTML = "Thanks for  your suggestions";
}
```